# How to delete existing NavHeader view while adding an updated one using NavigationView.addHeaderView()?

Tags: android, drawerlayout, navigation-drawer

I have a NavigationView in a Drawer Layout which contains a HeaderView followed by a Menu (as given in AndroidStudio's Navigation Drawer Activity's template). My Header contains an Image and couple of TextViews in a LinearLayout. I want to edit of one of the TextViews in the header from SharedPreferences. I use following function to do so

```
public void navUpdate()
{
        navigationView=(NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        linearLayout=(LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main, null);
        textView_nname=(TextView)linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView_nname);


        String name=sharedPreferences.getString("name","Your Name");
        textView_nname.setText(name);

        navigationView.removeHeaderView(linearLayout);
        navigationView.addHeaderView(linearLayout);
}
```

The problem is , though I've added the line

```
navigationView.removeHeaderView(linearLayout);
```

my previous headerview is still visible above the new one. And previous one is not updated. I read about the method navigationview.getHeaderAt() in many answers but believe me, that method is not available.

[Here's how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXDeU.jpg)

Is there any solution for this problem, if not is there any other way to do so?

Comment: "navigationview.getHeaderAt()...that method is not available." - I believe you want the `getHeaderView(int index)` method. Also, if you just want to change the text in a header's TextView, you don't need to completely replace the header. Use the aforementioned method to get the header, and the `findViewById()` method to access the TextView you want to change.

Comment: @MikeM.-   I'm sorry , my bad, I meant navigationView.getHeaderView() only. But you might wanna take look at http://i66.tinypic.com/sm3j21.png

Comment: Make sure you're using the most recent library version. That method was just added about [three months ago](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/cdccc4c6d5f1e40610ce4df4afeb1f99cbdb63e8%5E%21/#F2).

Comment: thank u so much. Its done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order for you to get the `Header` from the `NavigationView` you'll have to call `getHeaderView(int index)` for instance:

```
View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
textView_nname = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.textView_nname);
// set whatever you like on the textView.
```

Comment: This is the method I read about. but trust me, it is not available  http://i66.tinypic.com/sm3j21.png

Comment: Update your dependency to 23.1.1